# Validations showing errors even though values are being posted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I have the following model validations

```
  validates_presence_of :enddate
  validates_presence_of :startdate
```

This is what's being posted

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"QczhHQoDU7a0/WKnUnLlzQ9Aob/NQOj1naiwfOYIW1c=", 
"billsanddeposit"=>{"name"=>"Test Bill Item", 
"itemcategory_id"=>"2", "repeatsevery"=>"2", "startdate"=>"01/24/2013", "enddate"=>"01/31/2013", 
"deposit"=>"0", "amount"=>"100"}, "commit"=>"Create Billsanddeposit"}
```

And these are the errors that are showing up

```
Enddate can't be blank
Startdate can't be blank
```

These are datetime fields in the database, and when the scaffolding created the form originally it had the date_select.  I changed this to a text_field with a jquery datepicker on it, and now even though I can see the values are being posted as shown above I get the above errors indicating they aren't being seen.

Here's the entire model

```
class Billsanddeposit < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amount, :bankaccount_id, :deposit, :enddate, :itemcategory_id, :name, :repeatsevery, :repeattype_id, :startdate

  validates_presence_of :amount
  validates_presence_of :bankaccount_id
  validates_presence_of :itemcategory_id
  validates_presence_of :enddate
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :repeatsevery
  validates_presence_of :repeattype_id
  validates_presence_of :startdate


  belongs_to  :bankaccount
  belongs_to  :repeattype
  belongs_to  :itemcategory
  has_many    :ledgeritems
end
```

All I've done thus far is add the relationships and the validations.

Here's the controller, almost completely default

```
  def create
    @billsanddeposit = Billsanddeposit.new(params[:billsanddeposit])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @billsanddeposit.save
        @billsanddeposits = Billsanddeposit.joins(:bankaccount).where("bankaccounts.user_id = ?", current_user.id)
        @billsanddeposit = Billsanddeposit.new

        format.html { redirect_to @billsanddeposit, :notice => 'Billsanddeposit was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :json => @billsanddeposit, :status => :created, :location => @billsanddeposit }
      else
        @billsanddeposits = Billsanddeposit.joins(:bankaccount).where("bankaccounts.user_id = ?", current_user.id)

        format.html { render :action => "index" }
        format.json { render :json => @billsanddeposit.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try to parse the dates with `DateTime.parse(date)`

Comment: Is the controller the default scaffold?

Comment: do you have `attr_accessible` for `:enddate` and `:startdate`?

Comment: I've updated the question with the model and controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem from this blog: http://library.edgecase.com/american-date-parsing#tldr

It was because I was using the American date format.  By including the referenced gem it started working again.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted on comment but here is my response.

If you want save on your database `enddate` and `startdate` you must add `attr_accessible`

```
attr_accessible :enddate, :startdate
```

If you can receive these parameters on your action `created` Perhaps is a problem with the date format.

Also you should make sure that these attributes on your model are of type Date, Time...etc.

Regards!

Comment: I've updated the question with my full model and controller method.  As you can see it's all set like you're saying.  I'm not even validating the format, only that it's there.  When I created it I did set the startdate and enddate as a datetime property.

Comment: can you write inside of your create action on your controller e.g. `logger.info params[:billsanddeposit][:startdate]` and `logger.info params[:billsanddeposit][:startdate]`. After you can take a look to your log to see what values have this params and paste here please